# Stole a pre-war book at Mojave Outpost and lost a lot of gear -- what happened?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I was dressed as a member of NCR, and on a larf, decided to steal a meaningless item in the barracks (a pre-war book, specifically). I was wearing NCR armor and an NCR goggle helmet.

Once I did, no one turned red, but all of a sudden, I received a message stating I was no longer dressed as a member of the NCR, and several follow-up messages about items no longer being in my inventory. Several of them seemed to be things I ... um ... kind of stole from the Mojave Outpost. Several, however, were not things I took from the Outpost. (Though they did correspond, sort of, to stuff I looted out of NCRCF.)

What exactly just happened? I reloaded an autosave from entering the barracks, but I'm curious as to why so much loot/gear disappeared from my inventory upon stealing a piddly little pre-war book, but without anyone turning red and trying to kill me ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes, if you steal something while seen, rather than trying to kill you, people will take back the stolen goods.

Along with everything else you're carrying that you've ever stolen.

Comment: Well it seems that stealing from a fraction, their behaviour depends on how much Reputation you have with them. Also if you wear a fraction-specific armor, this fraction will be friendlier in all "bad things" you do.